# How can I mixed text and link together correctly by flexbox?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {

}
div,span,a{
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div><span>Here is the official site of google:</span><a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a><span>. You can search many things via the search engine of it.Google LLC is an American multinational technology company that specializes in Internet-related services and products, which include online advertising technologies, a search engine, cloud computing, software, and hardware.</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Well, it turns out to be this:
[image]

I want them mixed together well, just like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use flexbox... Why are you using flexbox?

Comment: never use flexbox for text container. what you are showing doesn't need flexbox

Comment: @D.Pardal What's the problem with it? Would you please tell me?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why I should not use it? And also, it seems it can not work also even I replace the flex to inline-block.

Comment: for the issue you are facing, flexbox is for *boxes* not for text. You don't need to replace it with inline block. You need to remove the flex you are applying to the div (also to span and a too, it's not needed)

Comment: @TemaniAfif OK, after I removed all. It works now.